# Keras Extraction of Informative Features in Text Using Weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, feature-extraction

I am working on a text classification project, and I would like to use `keras` to rank the importance of each word (token). My intuition is that I should be able to sort weights from the Keras model to rank the words.

Possibly I am having a simple issue using `argsort` or `tf.math.top_k`.

The complete code is from [Packt](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Natural-Language-Processing-with-Python-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter09/9.2%20Email_Classification.py)

I start by using `sklearn` to compute TF-IDF using the 10,000 most frequent words.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2, ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english',
                             max_features=10000, strip_accents='unicode', norm='l2')

x_train_2 = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train_preprocessed).todense()
x_test_2 = vectorizer.transform(x_test_preprocessed).todense()
```

I can view the list of words like this:

```
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names()[:10])
```

I then build and fit a model using Keras. Keras is using the tensorflow backend.

```
# Deep Learning modules
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import Adadelta, Adam, RMSprop
from keras.utils import np_utils

# Definiting hyper parameters
np.random.seed(1337)
nb_classes = 20
batch_size = 64
nb_epochs = 20

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(1000, input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(500))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

print(model.summary())

# Model Training
model.fit(x_train_2, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epochs, verbose=1)
```

I can then get weights like this:

```
weight = model.weights[0]
# Returns <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(10000, 1000) dtype=float32_ref>
```

Since the number of rows (10,000) is equal to the number of features, I think I am on the right track. I need to get a list of indices I can use to get feature names: `informative_features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()[sorted_indices]`.

I have tried to build a list using two different techniques:

1. `tf.nn.top_k`

   ```
   sorted_indices = tf.nn.top_k(weight)
   # Returns TopKV2(values=<tf.Tensor 'TopKV2_2:0' shape=(10000, 1) dtype=float32>, indices=<tf.Tensor 'TopKV2_2:1' shape=(10000, 1) dtype=int32>)
   ```

   I have not determined how to get a list from this result.
2. `argsort`

   ```
   sorted_indices = model.get_weights()[0].argsort(axis=0)
   print(sorted_indices.shape)
   # Returns (10000, 1000)
   ```

   Function `argsort` returns a matrix, but what I need is a one-dimensional list.

How can I use weights to rank text features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is not possible
first layer outputs 1000 value
each value binded with each feature with some weight value 
and same thing continues to end of network

if input directly binded classification layer and if it is trained then

```
tfidf =  Input(shape=(10000,))
output = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(tfidf)
model = Model(tfidf,output)
model.summary()

# train model ...

last_layer = model.layers[-1]
weights = last_layer.get_weights()[0]
for i in range(nb_classes):
    print('class : ',i,' ->  Feature : ',np.argmax(weights[:,i]) )
```